# Excel: Making Cell A Be Deleted if Value Exceeds Number

Tags: excel, if-statement, cells

I doubt this is possible, but wanted to ask anyway:

Let's say I have a raw input in Cell A, either linked from a different spreadsheet or put in manually.  In Cell B, there is a formula, probably an =IF statement, for which if Cell A is greater than X, it remains.  Otherwise, it will be deleted, raw input and all.  In addition, that deleted data would go to a different cell / spreadsheet, to store the deleted info.

This is, in essence, two questions.  I am pretty sure the second one could work with some knowhow, but the first one seems like a mess, if even possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not possible with formulas.  A formula cannot effect another cells value.  It will require vba.

Comment: If you still want this, have you written any VBA to solve this problem?

Comment: Thank you both for the answer.  I am not well versed in VBAs, and it isn't the most important thing.  But if you have a suggestion on how it could be done, I am welcome to try it.